# RStudio code runs on Windows, but identical code fails on Linux

Tags: r, linux, path, ubuntu-20.04

I have written code in R in RStudio on a Windows10 PC but need to execute the same code on a Virtual Linux Ubuntu 20.04 machine now. I have installed RStudio on the Ubuntu machine and adjusted the paths but it does not appear to work. What am I doing wrong?

The code I want to use is very simple. I have a folder within all my functions are saved as .R files. I source all the files and then add them through the code.

Code on Windows:

```
Library_path = "Z:/R_Code/MyLibrary/" #set path to folder
source_files <- list.files(Library_path , "*.R$")  # locate all .R files
map(paste0(Library_path, source_files), source)
```

Output Windows:

```
> source_files
 [1] "function1.R"                           
 [2] "function2.R"                                   
 [3] "function3.R"
```

Code on Linux:

```
Library_path = "/home/username/pathToFolder/R_code/MyLibrary" #set path to folder
source_files <- list.files(Library_path , "*.R$")  # locate all .R files
map(paste0(Library_path, source_files), source)
```

Output Linux:

```
> source_files
character(0)
```

Do the file paths need to be specified differently in RStudio if it runs on Ubuntu?
The location of the files on the Ubuntu system is on a mounted share drive, could that be a problem?

Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, between win10 and ubuntu 20.04. Some thoughts: (1) `pattern=` should be a regular expression (as opposed to a glob pattern), and starting a regex with `*` (zero or more of the preceding char/class) does not make sense; while it is not an error, it is not quite right (to me). (2) Similarly, if I'm interpreting correctly, it should probably be `"\\.R$"`, otherwise your `.` could match anything, including `"file.taR"`. (3) No need for your `paste0`, just use `list.files(..., full.names=TRUE)`, it is the canonical (and more robust) way, imo.

Comment: @r2evans Thank you for your reply, you are absolutely right "\\.R$" is better. If I run `list.files( pattern="\\.R$", full.names=True)''` without a path specified it returns all the files from the working directory, but as soon as I enter a path it no longer finds any files. Am I entering the path wrong? On Windows I always used path = "/Folders/" and it worked.

Comment: You misunderstand. `list.files(Library_Path, "\\.R$", full.names=TRUE)` is what I recommend. Later, you can replace `map(paste0(Library_path, source_files), source)` with `map(source_files, source)`.

Comment: @r2evans Yes I got that, but my problem is that `list.files(Library_Path, "\\.R$", full.names=TRUE)` only returns any files (the files from the working directory) if I leave Library_Path empty. So when I try to enter a Library_Path (for example `/folder1/`) it no longer finds any files within that folder. How should I enter the path to a subfolder of my working directory as Library_Path?

Answer (score 1):

Thank you @r2evans for your help.

I found my mistake: The code works on Windows and Ubuntu, the problem was that the file path systems work differently.

On Windows:

```
path = "/folder/"
```

On Linux:

```
path = "./folder/"
```

If the point is added it works.

Comment: That's certainly a problem, wasn't clear in the question but now I see the issue. Glad you found it.